# Getting Blady placed ()'s error when trying to run a qt in vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm getting an unknown error 'Badly placed ()'s' when attempting to build a QT widget .

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import sys
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QtGui.QWidget()
window.setGeometry(50,50,500,300)
window.setWindowTitle("pyqt window")
window.show()
```

A empty window with "pyqt window" as title

Comment: Which line is the error happening on? There don't seem to be any bad parentheses in the code you posted.

Comment: it seems problem with VSCode, not with code in Python. Run it without VSCode to confirm it.

Comment: It builds successfully on sublime , but I can't see a UI since sublime doesn't support Ui.

Comment: any one got any idea how to configure vscode to support this

Comment: as for me it should works without any problems. If VSCode makes problem then better go to VSCode's webpage and they should helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked after adding sys.exit(app.exec_()) to the code